# Set different style by project path at Atom-editor

Tags: css, atom-editor

I have a couple of network storage, for example '\dev', '\qa', etc...
I am trying at Atom IDE to set a different style to the projects by the path base.
For projects that located on '\**dev**\www\example\' the curser will be green, and for projects that located on '\**qa**\www\example\' the curser will be red.
Is it possible? if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following to your `styles.less` (**File > Stylesheet…**)

```
atom-pane[data-active-item-path*="'\dev\www\example\"] {
  .cursor {
    color: green;
  }
}

atom-pane[data-active-item-path*="\qa\www\example\"] {
  .cursor {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

**Note:** I'm using the *contains* attribute selector (`*=`), but you might want to look at all [available options](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/) to see which fits your needs best.